# Has Russia considered accepting migrants that want to reach Europe?

Tags: russian-federation, immigration, population

[This article](https://www.worldpoliticsreview.com/insights/27852/russia-needs-immigrants-but-lacks-a-coherent-immigration-policy) argues that Russia, like many other countries, faces a population decline that must be tackled sooner or later:

> The shrinking of Russia’s population overall, and especially the
> working-age population, is inevitable. According to the median
> forecast provided by the Russian Federal State Statistics Service, the
> population is expected to decrease by 2.5 million people by 2035, a
> roughly 1.7 percent drop. The active working-age population will
> likely see an even steeper decline of 3.1 million people.
>
> (..)
>
> **For Russia, immigration is not a matter of choice. It is a matter of
> necessity, in order to sustain the population**.

Considering that [there are still many migrants aiming for Europe](https://www.dw.com/en/turkey-will-not-stop-refugees-who-want-to-go-to-europe/a-52568981), has Russia considered accepting a fraction of them?

Comment: Russia is accepting significant numbers of migrant workers from the former USSR.

Comment: You might be interested: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48103/why-dont-countries-experiencing-population-decline-take-isis-refugees

Comment: Russia can only considere (or not) accepting migrants that want to reach Russia

Answer (score -9):

The main point of the article is somewhat irrelevant. The EU proves that "multiculturalism", i.e., assimilating and co-living of different groups of people, stopped working at some point - just watch the increase of terrorism and social unrest in Europe. Therefore, it is irrelevant to consider arbitrary migrants as a solution to the problem (which really exists, and need to be solved).

Russia is accepting migrant workers from the former USSR (mostly Russian-speaking), but not for solving population problem - at least mainly. It is a solution of unemployment in former USSR Asian republics, which lose their factories and industry during the 90s. Which, in its turn, should be solved to increase stability in Central Asia.

The population problem can hardly be solved by migrants. Russian [maternal capital](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1023323/russia-maternal-capital-benefits/) works better:

[image]

Of course, problem is present (and is a **real problem**, one of consequences of USSR dissolving and nightmare of the 90s), its solving is in process, and cannot be called "easy and cheap". But it definitely cannot be solved by arbitrary migrants.

Comment: "EU proves, that "multiculturalism" (assimilating and co-living of different groups of people) stopped working at some point - just watch nowadays uprising of terrorism and people unrest in Europe.". This assumption that multiculturalism causes terrorism and unrest is very questionable. Do you have sources proving this causation?

Comment: My point was, that, along with fair migrants, Europe accepted enough radicals, and, with foreign population growth, it becomes harder to co-exist

Comment: The causes of terrorism are complex and it's not the topic of the question, but the equation "immigration => terrorism" is definitely misleading. The link between immigration and civil unrest is even thinner, most indications point to poor economic conditions as a much more important factor (arguably they could also play a role in the likelihood of radicalization). To be clear, the fact that a country doesn't want to accept indiscriminate immigration is common and there can be good reasons to it, but linking this to a dubious claim about immigration in the EU looks like a bad explanation.

Comment: "The EU proves" - interesting point. I'd like to see that proof because I haven't seen anything like that yet. However, it's irrelevant to the question.